# Schur decomposition of a matrix.

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, schur-decomposition

Let $E$ be a symmetric matrix then is it possible to find a unitary matrix $U$ such that the diagonal entries of $U^*EU$ are zero?

Comment: This might be an interesting question if $E$ were *skew*-symmetric (in which case I suspect it might be true, but I don't know off the top of my head), or if you asked that the *off*-diagonal entries be zero (in which case it's Sylvester's law of inertia). Was one of those what you meant to ask?

Comment: $E$ and $U^* E U$ are conjugated matrices, hence they have the same eigenvalues and the same trace. So what you are asking may be possible only if $\text{Tr}(E)=0$, for starters.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider the case that $E$ is the identity.